# The name 'model' does not exist in the current context?

Tags: c#, razor

In my Razor application i can't use `@model` as it throws an exception of `The name 'model' does not exist in the current context` What i already tried is

1. Putting a `web.config` file in the same folder as the views.
2. Playing with `web.config` file because i think that it is what
   causes the problem.

*Website layout:*

[image]

*`web.config`:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Version" value="3.0" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Packages installed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.2" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.9.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
</packages>
```

Additional notes:

- I already tried to create a new MVC application and copy it's
  `web.config` without luck, so up there i explained everything in
  detail in the hope that someone detects the mistake.

Comment: Can you show your view?

Comment: @WilliamMelani It is a little bit hard as it contains project code... but it is a normal view with `@model` Type at the top then `@{ BLABLABLA CODE... }`

Comment: you have modified the format of your MVC site, removed at least one key file, and changed the name of a key folder.  You *might* be able to reconstruct the missing files, or change the references that expect specific folder names, but it's not something we can guide you through each piece of here.